# UIPopover delegate issue

Tags: ipad

I am facing one issue regarding the UIPopoverController. When I execute following

```
- (void)showPopover:(id)sender 
{
        iPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav]; 
        iPopOver.delegate = self;
        [iPopOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

Application crashes and found this error

> -[IPadController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance
>   0xc93b510

Not able to debug this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sender argument is not a UIBarButtonItem or is an outdated reference.

You should replace your code with:

```
  [iPopOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:myButton
   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

where myButton is a reference to your UIBarButtonItem.

Good luck!